# "Evaluate function" in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, string, function, evaluation

I want to know if exists an "evaluate" function in C++ like the Matlab one.

In practise, I need a function that can interprets a string like a command line.

thanks for the answers.

Comment: Hi, Cavs85! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could include a link to documentation for Matlab's `evaluate` function. Since I don't know what it does, I can't tell you what C++ function is like it.

Comment: [`eval(expression)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) "executes *expression*, a string containing any valid MATLAB expression." Do you want a C++ function that can execute an arbitrary MATLAB expression? Or do you want a C++ function that can execute an arbitrary C++ expression? Or something else?

Comment: This sounds like an "XY problem" http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem.  @Cavs85, please describe your end goal, not just what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 6):

If you are actually trying to "evaluate" C++ source code within a running C++ application, then basically no - it's not a feature specified by the language.

There are **interpreters** for subsets of C++ (e.g. CInt, Ch and UnderC) - they may be able to run your C++ program if it's a relatively simple one.  Alternatively, some can be embedded within a compiled C++ program to allow some run-time source code evaluation, but with limited access to and ability to change the pre-compiled code and its variables.

It's also possible for a running program to **invoke the compiler** and dynamically load/link a resultant library, but this is a very unusual practice and not without performance, security and interoperability issues:

- creating a new process for the compiler, compiling and linking is a relatively resource-hungry and slow operation, but once the library's linked the new code can be executed at normal out-of-line function call speeds
- the usual issues with executing an external process

  - ensuring the path and compiler executable name can't be changed by malicious inputs to the program
  - that no malware is substituted for or infecting the compiler
  - on-the-fly source code doesn't contain statements like `system()`, `exec()`, `unlink()` calls, abuse network connectivity, chew unwarranted CPU/memory/descriptors etc.
- the pre-compiled C++ program can't be modified or easily/deeply probed by the newly linked code, so the main mechanisms for new behaviour must have been designed in to the pre-compiled application already: expectations for newly accessible variables, functions, and factory methods / virtual dispatch.

If you actually need something more limited, like the ability to **evaluate mathematical expressions or logical predicates**, possibly expressed in a C++-source style, perhaps reading or setting some of your values, then various more limited and specialised libraries and embedded interpreted are available.  There are even libraries for creating such parsers, such as the boost spirit library.

Finally, interpreters for other languages - Lua, Ruby, Python, Perl, TCL etc. - may be embedded in the C++ application, sporting various approaches to interoperability and security.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `system()`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: That will let you call some other program that provides an `eval`-style function, let's not confuse it with a standard C++ expression evaluator.

Comment: Is `system()` available on windows as well? The Q mentions `visual studio`.

Comment: @Ben, since the OP asked for "a function that can interprets a string like a command line", I used `system()`.  You are correct that it is not equivalent to Matlab's `eval`

Comment: @Als: It's in `stdlib.h`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Comment: +1: Although that may not be what the OP wants, it's certainly what he asked for...